# qml Surface3D draw random lines to origin point

Tags: qt, qml, data-visualization, qt-quick, qt3d

I want to to draw 3d surface using some points, I use Surface3D to draw that surface.
The problem is Surface3D always create random lines from beginning and ending of surface to the origin point (0,0,0), however the origin point doesn't exist in my cloud points.

For example, I run this code
main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtDataVisualization 1.3

Rectangle {
id: mainview
width: 1024
height: 768
color: surfacePlot.theme.windowColor

Data {
    id: surfaceData
}

Item {
    id: surfaceView
    width: mainview.width
    height: mainview.height
    anchors.top: mainview.top
    anchors.left: mainview.left

    ColorGradient {
        id: surfaceGradient
        ColorGradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "darkslategray" }
        ColorGradientStop { id: middleGradient; position: 0.25; color: "peru" }
        ColorGradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "red" }
    }

    Surface3D {
        id: surfacePlot
        width: surfaceView.width
        height: surfaceView.height
        //! [7]
        theme: Theme3D {
            type: Theme3D.ThemeStoneMoss
            font.family: "STCaiyun"
            font.pointSize: 35
            colorStyle: Theme3D.ColorStyleRangeGradient
            baseGradients: [surfaceGradient]
        }
        //! [7]
        shadowQuality: AbstractGraph3D.ShadowQualityNone
        selectionMode: AbstractGraph3D.SelectionSlice | AbstractGraph3D.SelectionItemAndRow
        scene.activeCamera.cameraPreset: Camera3D.CameraPresetIsometricLeft
        axisX.min: 0
        axisX.max: 500
        axisY.min: 20
        axisY.max: 300
        axisZ.min: 0
        axisZ.max: 500
        axisX.segmentCount: 10
        axisX.subSegmentCount: 2
        axisX.labelFormat: "%i"
        axisZ.segmentCount: 10
        axisZ.subSegmentCount: 2
        axisZ.labelFormat: "%i"
        axisY.segmentCount: 5
        axisY.subSegmentCount: 2
        axisY.labelFormat: "%i"
        axisY.title: "Height"
        axisX.title: "Latitude"
        axisZ.title: "Longitude"

        //! [5]
        Surface3DSeries {
            id: surfaceSeries
            flatShadingEnabled: false
            drawMode: Surface3DSeries.DrawSurface

            ItemModelSurfaceDataProxy {
                itemModel: surfaceData.model
                rowRole: "longitude"
                columnRole: "latitude"
                yPosRole: "height"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Data.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Item {
property alias model: dataModel

//! [0]
ListModel {
    id: dataModel
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 200; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 210; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 220; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 230; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 240; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 250; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 260; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 270; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 280; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 290; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 300; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 310; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 320; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 330; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 340; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 350; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 360; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 370; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 380; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 390; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 400; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 390; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 380; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 370; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 360; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 350; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 340; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 330; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 320; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 310; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 300; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 290; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 280; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 270; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 260; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 250; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 240; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 230; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 220; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 210; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 200; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 190; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 180; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 170; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 160; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 150; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 140; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 130; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 120; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 110; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 100; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 90; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 80; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 70; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 60; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 50; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 40; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 30; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 20; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 10; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 0; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 10; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 20; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 30; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 40; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 50; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 60; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 70; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 80; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 90; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 100; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 110; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 120; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 130; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 140; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 150; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 160; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 170; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 180; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 190; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 200; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 210; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 220; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 230; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 240; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 250; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 260; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 270; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 280; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 290; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 300; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 310; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 320; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 330; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 340; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 350; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 360; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 370; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 380; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 390; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 400; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 390; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 380; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 370; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 360; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 350; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 340; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 330; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 320; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 310; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 300; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 290; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 280; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 270; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 260; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 250; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 240; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 230; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 220; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 210; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 200; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 190; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 180; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 170; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 160; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 150; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 140; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 130; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 120; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 110; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 100; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 90; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 80; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 70; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 60; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 50; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 40; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 30; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 20; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 10; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 0; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 10; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 20; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 30; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 40; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 50; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 60; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 70; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 90; latitude: 80; height: 50; }
}
}
```

I suppose that a thin surface should be rendered, but the following surface is rendered
[Result of running the above code, There are random lines to the origin point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BjQW.png)

Can anyone explain why there are lines between edges of surface and origin point and how can I eliminate them ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after a few tries I figured out that **ListModel** elements to plot **Surface3D** should be defined like this, for example:
SurfaceData.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.1

ListModel {
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 36.00793 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 35.85623 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 35.80596 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 35.86737 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 36.19770 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 36.59485 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 37.05033 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 37.49552 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 37.85025 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62104; yPos: 38.12154 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 36.01458 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 35.95255 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 35.95918 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 36.04505 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 36.35229 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 36.71176 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 37.11597 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 37.49729 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 37.81175 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62125; yPos: 38.06440 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 36.32553 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 36.33961 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 36.38792 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 36.48003 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 36.70997 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 36.97702 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 37.27619 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 37.55237 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 37.79258 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62146; yPos: 37.99829 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 36.78084 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 36.86065 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 36.93751 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 37.01362 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 37.14435 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 37.29476 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 37.46340 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 37.61312 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 37.75639 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62167; yPos: 37.89418 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.21138 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.34629 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.44530 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.50286 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.53003 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.55219 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.57159 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.61607 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.68665 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62186; yPos: 37.78460 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.55103 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.72618 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.83209 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.84795 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.77734 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.69717 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.61931 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.61611 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.66154 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62208; yPos: 37.75663 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 37.85260 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 38.02822 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 38.11202 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 38.07137 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 37.94499 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 37.82461 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 37.73309 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 37.73527 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 37.79184 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62229; yPos: 37.90438 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.18437 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.31119 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.34892 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.27476 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.15377 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.04902 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 37.98370 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.01583 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.10371 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62250; yPos: 38.25076 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.51958 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.57501 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.56699 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.49122 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.40864 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.35099 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.33998 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.42698 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.55856 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62271; yPos: 38.73426 }

    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85896; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.80311 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85875; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.80242 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85854; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.76921 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85833; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.71027 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85813; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.67825 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85792; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.68442 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85771; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.75226 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85750; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 38.89324 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85729; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 39.05473 }
    ListElement{ xPos: -73.85708; zPos: 45.62292; yPos: 39.22962 }
}
```

[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i56uY.png).

So there should be equal intervals between "*blocks of data* with same **Z**-values" (or **longitude** in your case). And the set of **X**-values should be the same in every *block* of the model. For example in your case:

```
import QtQuick 2.1

ListModel {
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 200; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 210; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 220; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 230; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 240; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 250; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 260; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 270; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 280; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 290; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 300; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 310; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 320; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 330; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 340; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 350; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 360; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 370; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 380; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 50; latitude: 390; height: 54; }

    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 390; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 380; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 370; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 360; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 350; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 340; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 330; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 320; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 310; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 300; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 290; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 280; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 270; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 260; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 250; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 240; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 230; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 220; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 210; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 60; latitude: 200; height: 54; }

    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 200; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 210; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 220; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 230; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 240; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 250; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 260; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 270; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 280; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 290; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 300; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 310; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 320; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 330; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 340; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 350; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 360; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 370; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 380; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 70; latitude: 390; height: 54; }

    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 390; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 380; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 370; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 360; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 350; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 340; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 330; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 320; height: 51; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 310; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 300; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 290; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 280; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 270; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 260; height: 53; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 250; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 240; height: 54; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 230; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 220; height: 50; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 210; height: 52; }
    ListElement{ longitude: 80; latitude: 200; height: 50; }
}
```

[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rnqs.png).

So if the "same **Z** *blocks of data*" are not equal then Qt reduces the unknown data in incomplete blocks to (0;0;0), which leads to strange behavior.
[More info about QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#details).
Also [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemmodelsurfacedataproxy.html#MultiMatchBehavior-enum) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtdatavisualization-itemmodelsurfacedataproxy.html#multiMatchBehavior-prop) you can find useful information about situation when your **ItemModel**'s data are taken at irregular intervals.